# How to check page was loaded in __init__?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have base class init

```
class BasePage:

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.driver = context.driver
```

and later when create any new Page I used inheritance:

```
class LandingPage(BasePage):

    def __init__(self, context):
        super().__init__(context)
```

what I want is to check that every next page is loaded using **init**

```
def __init__(self, context, is_loaded_check=True):
    self.driver = context.driver
    if is_loaded_check:
        self.page_was_loaded()
    else:
        raise Exception('page was not loaded!!')

def page_was_loaded(self):
    self.elem = context.driver.find_elem_by_xpath(locator)
```

but tests are stuck on the white screen even when I put time.sleep 30sec

Comment: When do you call `driver.get("www.url.com")`?

Comment: Moshe Slavin I got goto method in BasePage class